# Search & switch open files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I open some files in Visual Studio Code (e.g. `code some_path/some_file.py some_other_path/some_other_file.py`) it seems that *Find in Files* and *Go to File* doesn't work.

If I search for some text only the file in the currently active tab is included. Only if I select other tabs once those files are then also considered if I repeat the search.

Also other files do not appear in *Go to File* unless I give those tabs the focus at least once and they populate the list because they are "recently opened".

I am *not* opening a folder with files in it.

In SublimeText *Find in Files* can do this. Or I let `:vimgrep` search all buffers in Vim.

How would I do this with VS Code?
I often search a large code base (organized in multiple repositories and paths) with *ack* or *ripgrep* and feed a list of files to the editor. E.g. `code $(rg --files-with-matches 'some feature' **/test*.py)`.

My system:

```
code --version
1.11.1
d9484d12b38879b7f4cdd1150efeb2fd2c1fbf39

> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.4
BuildVersion:   16E195
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "I am not opening a folder with files in it." I think that you will find these work if opening a folder.

Comment: Yes - opening a folder works. But I would like to avoid that. Because the files I open are often spread across multiple paths/directories. And I would like to feed the list of files from the command line to use the result of a search via `find`, `ack` or other tools.

Comment: Well, I started looking here on stak overflow an had to move on without test ideas. You may try assigning a soft link to each file found with grep and put them a working directory. I'm thinking the directory could be pwd/searchTerm. To Code tese soft links are in one directory.